# Data passed to a slot is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mobile, material-ui, vuetify.js

I'm trying to build a small chat application that works on Mobile as well. I want to hide a new message button when someone goes into conversation (floating action button) and use a different button on desktop. I have a dialog to create a new chat group.

```
            <v-dialog transition="dialog-top-transition" max-width="600">
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }" v-if="!showMessageList">
                    <v-btn fab dark color="primary" fixed right bottom v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" class="d-flex d-sm-none">
                        <v-icon dark>mdi-message-outline</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                </template>
                <template v-slot:default="dialog">
                    <v-card min-height="70vh">
                        <v-toolbar color="primary" dark>New Message
                            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                            <v-btn icon @click="dialog.value = false">
                                <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                        </v-toolbar>
                        <v-card-text>
                            <v-text-field label="Find contact" hide-details="auto" v-model="contactQuery" @keydown="searchContact"></v-text-field>
                            <contacts :contacts="contacts" :user="user" v-on:new-group="addGroup"></contacts>
                        </v-card-text>

                    </v-card>
                </template>
            </v-dialog>
```

app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: vuetify,
    data: {
        //
        user: {},
        contactQuery: "",
        contacts: [],
        showMessageList: true,
    },
    created() {
        this.showMessageList = !this.isMobile();
    }
    methods: {
        isMobile() {
            return window.innerWidth < 500;
        },
        openMessages() {
            this.showMessageList = true;
        },
        hideMessages() {
            if (this.isMobile()) {
                this.showMessageList = false;
            }
        },
        showGroups() {
            if (this.isMobile()) {
                return !this.showMessageList;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

template

```
<chat-groups :user="user" :groups="groups" :curr-group="group" :is-mobile="isMobile" v-on:group-change="changeCurrGroup" v-on:open-messages="openMessages"></chat-groups>
```

ChatGroups.vue

```
export default {
    props: ["groups", "currGroup", "user", "isMobile"],
    data() {
        return {
            selectedGroup: this.currGroup
        }
    },
    methods: {
//...
        openMessages() {
            if (this.isMobile()) {
                this.$emit("open-messages");
            }
        },
```

The problem is with `showMessageList`. It only hides the button for the first time. How to make it reactive? How to hide the dialog from a different place (another button in a different container)

Comment: can you share like code sandbox link? it will be helpful to debug and reproduce

Comment: Hi Sri, I think this was caused by some weird css clash. In the end I decided to skip dialog and use vue-router. The second question is till vaild. How to open/close the dialog from a different place?

Comment: We can do that programmatically by setting the v-dialog's v-model. You can make use of vuex/pinia to do the same. As I said, if you can share like a code sandbox or codepen, I can try to make edits

Answer (score 0):

Add an eventlistener to the window like so:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() { return { windowWidth: window.innerWidth } },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth
      console.log(this.isMobile)
    })
  },
  computed: {
    isMobile() {
      return this.windowWidth <= 768
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: The problem is not with detecting if this is mobile. The problem is that v-if="!showMessageList" is not reactive

Comment: yes, it;s in the tags